# Кодировать строку UTF-8 в URL-код php, js

Tags: javascript, php

Решение возможно на php и\или js

Есть ф-я urlencode (php),  которая преобразует спец. символы в url-код:

> Возвращает строку, в которой все не цифро-буквенные символы, кроме -_. должны быть заменены знаком процента (%)

А мне нужно латинские буквы и цифры также кодировать.
Собственно, нужно открывать сайт с параметрами логина и пароля (которые нужно закодировать).

Comment: пример строки ввода и вывода

Comment: $login = "OIUGsefIUFEA";
$password = "lmnkefLJfmw";
https://site.ua/testreg.php?login=$login&password=$password&email=

Comment: Не нужно так делать.

Comment: Что можете посоветовать? Доступа к конечному сайту (куда передаю данные) нет.

Comment: Какова цель этого. От кого пытаетесь скрыть логин/пароль ? как проходит соединение, через браузер клиента или напрямую сервер-сервер. И да, если это увидит клиент то поверьте, читать % умеет очень много людей

Comment: @Mike на корп. портале будет страница, пользователи при открытии этой страницы будут видеть ссылки на сайты, куда собственно и нужно передавать параметры. Это нужно для удобства и экономии времени на вводы данных на конечных сайтах. Да, при нажатии по ссылке какую-то долю секунды эти данные можно увидеть в строке браузера, но это происходит очень быстро, в истории также не видно параметров, только конечная страничка.

Comment: если пользователь захочет он откроет консоль браузера и на вкладке network увидит все произошедшие запросы и сможет на них любоваться сколько угодно времени. а разницы между закодированных % и открытым текстом паролями нет практически ни какой. так что нет смысла это делать. Если нужна безопасность, заводите собственную систему идентификации пользователя, а сайты открываете не в браузере пользователя, а через собственный сайт, который в этом случае выступает как прокси, т.е. запрос на конечный сайт с паролем ваш сервер всегда делает сам, а все что тот вернет транслирует пользователю

Comment: Проверял, в network этих данных не видно (сразу же при успешном логине перебрасывает на другую страницу). При неправильном тоже не видно. И страница открывается в новой вкладке, а network ловит на первой.

Comment: В любом случае это не имеет значения. раз данные попали на клиента значит клиент их увидеть может. И легкое кодирование ничего не меняет. так что ваш вопрос в данной постановке не имеет смысла. можете конечно просто заменить каждый символ на % и код символа в шестнадцеричке